# download/backup multiple outlook emails into multiple files

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook-2016, export

I want to backup/download all my emails from Outlook 2016 and store them in a folder. To make things worst, it seems some emails are somehow archived (in the older section, I can't see the oldest emails and there is a message like this: "There are more items in this folder on the server" "Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange"; mail to keep offline is set to 1 year - in File > Account Settings > Account Settings > Change Account).

Now, I know:

1. you can make a big Outlook Data file (.pst) (File > Open&Export > Import&Export wizzard > Export to a file), or
2. you can go to Control Panel > Mail (32-bit) > Data Files and check where your emails are stored and then copy the file(s), or
3. you can drag-and-drop each email to a folder (doing so, a msg file is created)

But, I'm more interested in having multiple files (one for each email) so that if ones will prove useless I can delete them. I was wondering is there an automatic way to do this (so that you end up with each email in one file)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> To make things worst, it seems some emails are somehow archived (in the older section, I can't see the oldest emails and there is a message like this: "There are more items in this folder on the server" "Click here to view more on Microsoft Exchange"; mail to keep offline is set to 1 year - in File > Account Settings > Account Settings > Change Account).

Based on my experiences, this is not an archive but a cache mode. In this mode, a copy of your mailbox is saved on your computer. This copy provides quick access to your data, and it is frequently updated with the server that runs Microsoft Exchange.

According to your description, I noticed that you want to automatically back up all your messages. It is recommended that you try to archive older items automatically, which can keep your messages in a PST file without manual operation. For more information, please refer to: [Archive older items automatically](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-older-items-automatically-25f44f07-9b80-4107-841c-41dc38296667).

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 0):

This tool looks suitable for that and it's available for Windows and Linux:

***readpst** is a program that can read an Outlook PST (Personal Folders) file and convert it into an mbox file, a format suitable for KMail, a recursive mbox structure, or separate emails. https://linux.die.net/man/1/readpst*

Or maybe any other similar tool, even if it does not separate all emails, it may convert the Outlook format into MBOX format, which is plaintext and you could create a simple script that separates each email from that plaintext file into individual plaintext files.